# Issue with delays in Passenger/nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I have a Rails application that is run by Phusion Passenger Standalone (where nginx is built-in). I've enabled the access log both in nginx and in my Rails application. I've seen requests where the access log from nginx reports the request taking, for example, 10 seconds, while the access log from Rails reports it takes less than a second.

In the nginx access log I'm including, among other things, the following variables: $request_time, `$connection_requests`, `$connections_active`, `$connections_reading`, `$connections_writing` and `$connections_waiting`. As far as I understand, `$connections_active` is the number of requests currently in nginx, regardless if they're currently being processed by nginx or the Rails application. If the value of `$connections_active` is greater than the number of Passenger workers, there's a queue in nginx. The thing is that this value is never greater than the number of workers. I don't see why nginx would not forward the request to an available worker.

This issue is quite hard to consistently reproduce, there doesn't seem to be a pattern on when this occurs. It occurs, most of the time, on the most frequently used request paths, but I assume that's because they're the most frequently used.

Is there a way to get out some more information from Passenger/nginx on why the requests are stuck/delayed? Or any other ideas how to solve this.

Please let me know if there's any more information that is needed.